# Specify plot order per row when using facets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

```
d=expand.grid(obs=0:10, benchmark=c('antlr', 'bloat', 'chart', 'eclipse', 'fop', 'hsqldb', 'jython', 'luindex', 'lusearch', 'pmd', 'xalan'), gc=c('CopyMS', 'GenCopy', 'GenImmix', 'GenMS', 'Immix'), opt=c('on', 'off'), heapSize=seq(from=1.5, to=4, by=0.5))
d$time = rexp(nrow(d), 0.01)+1000
d$time = d$time + abs(d$heapSize-3)*100
d$time[d$opt=='on'] = d$time[d$opt=='on']-200

d$time[d$opt=='on' & d$benchmark=='bloat'] = d$time[d$opt=='on' & d$benchmark=='bloat'] + 190
d$time[d$opt=='on' & d$benchmark=='pmd' & d$gc=='Immix'] = d$time[d$opt=='on' & d$benchmark=='pmd' & d$gc=='Immix'] + 600


ggplot() +
  facet_wrap(~benchmark) +
  geom_boxplot(data=d, mapping=aes(x=opt, y=time, color=opt))
```

this code above makes a faceted plot with 4 columns.

I am wondering is it possible to specify which plots are on which row? For example if I want "antlr" and "bloat" and "chart" on row 1; "eclipse" and "fop and "hsqldb" and "jython" on row 2; "luindex" on row 3; and the rest on row 4. Is this possible? Also, is it possible to add a key word at the beginning of each row to the left most plot with a descriptive word?
Such as row 1 would read "ROW A"; row 2 would read "ROW B" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ncol number.

```
ggplot() +
  facet_wrap(~benchmark, ncol = 3) +
  geom_boxplot(data=d, mapping=aes(x=opt, y=time, color=opt))
```

If you want more specific order then use:

```
ggplot(data=d) +
  facet_wrap(.~factor(benchmark,levels = c('Name of Graph 1','Name of Graph 2', 'Name of Graph 3', 'Name of Graph etc'),ordered = TRUE), ncol = 3) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping=aes(x=opt, y=time, color=opt))
```

Comment: thank you but what if there is a different number of plots for each row?

Comment: I think you will need grid.arrange, this may help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html